# Laravel DomPdf questions

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5, dompdf

I use Laravel,and I need to convert html code from Ckeditor and put it to pdf file. I know that with this can help to me DomPdf , but I cant find any documentation to it. Only some basic code.

I need to make footer at all pages in pdf file.

Dompdf can do it? If you know how - can you help me please.

Comment: Have you tried any package

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf i thnking using this you can do

Comment: @Shibon  I use this package, but there no information how to do footer or some other settings

Comment: Have you searched in google
https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1190

Comment: @Shibon Yes,but its not work because I use Ckeditor

Comment: I suggest you use mPdf. You can do a lot more with this package and also it has a good documentation. https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf

Comment: @MortezaRajabi Can you help me to instal it in laravel? I tried, but its write me error about undefinded methods. Sorry if its stupid question, but I need it (

Comment: @AlexanderYefremov install this package. https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf. It is a wrapper for mPDF and makes the usage of mPDF easier.

Comment: @MortezaRajabi I done it. But when I write a sinple code from tutorial its write error       Call to undefined method niklasravnsborg\LaravelPdf\Facades\Pdf::SetTitle()                                                                                use PDF;

function generate_pdf() {
 $data = [
  'foo' => 'bar'
 ];
 $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.document', $data);
 return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');
}

Comment: @MortezaRajabi yes

Comment: The setTitle() method is called in the Pdf.php of the mentioned package. $this->mpdf->SetTitle( $this->getConfig('title') ); There is a config file in vendor/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf/src/config. make sure you set them all.

Comment: It's important when asking a question to indicate what you're tried (with code samples if possible) and what your results are. For example, how are you compiling the document? Is the entirety of the content coming from CKEditor or do you use multiple content sources (e.g. a standard HTML template)?

Comment: @AlexanderYefremov Did you solve your problem?